# How can I get the values from the URL and using that value fetch data from the database

Tags: php

I have made a custom link that will redirect the users to view other users profile.

How can I get the value of `id` that is being passed in the custom link on the `view_profile.php` page and pull the data from DB

```
echo'<a name="view_profile" href="view_profile.php?id='.$query_row['id'].'">'.'<img src="'.$query_row["profilepics"].'" height="50px" width="50px" class="img-circle"/>'." ".'<strong>'.$query_row["firstname"]." ".$query_row["lastname"].'</strong></a> ';associated with it?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're pulling data from a database, and accepting $_GET/$_REQUEST/$_POST params without filtering, I would suggest at least adding an intval():

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
```

This way you cast your input to an integer, so it's not vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it via the GET superglobal.

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that through.

```
<?php
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are successfully redirected or land on the view_profile.php page, then just simply place this code on view_profile.php page:

```
<?php $id = $_GET['id']; ?>
```

You will simply recieve the id value in your $id variable.